# How to set condition inside prop based on state value in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props, use-state

I am using component `<MapboxGL.UserLocation` to get current user coords and in this component there is a prop `onUpdate` which get the current location of the user and pass it to a function, what I want is before call the function inside the prop  check the state value if it is true or false and only if the state value true the function will be triggered, I have done the following but all times it call the function `onUserLocationUpdate(location)` even if the state is false

```
<MapboxGL.UserLocation
              renderMode="normal"
              visible={true}
              onUpdate={location => {
                            if (!isStartL) {
                                console.log("not start yet")
                            } else {
                                onUserLocationUpdate(location)
                            }
                        }}
   />
```

and here is the state I am using `const [isStartL, setisStartL] = useState(false);`

**Update** complete code:

```
const app = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isStartL, setisStartL] = useState(false);
const onUserLocationUpdate = (location) => {

console.log(location);

}
  const renderLocationInfo = () => {
     
        if (!isStartL) {
            return (<View style={styles.rcontainer}>
                <Text style={styles.btn}>Press start when you are in the same location </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={setisStartL(true)} >Start</TouchableOpacity>
            </View>)

        }
    }

 return (
       <View style={styles.matchParent}>

                <MapboxGL.MapView
                   
                    surfaceView={true}
                    zoomLevel={15}
                    logoEnabled={false}
                    style={styles.matchParent}

                >

                    <MapboxGL.UserLocation
                        renderMode="normal"
                        visible={true}

                        onUpdate={(location) => {
                            (!isStartL) ? console.log("not start yet") : onUserLocationUpdate(location)
                        }}
                    />
                    <MapboxGL.Camera

                        followZoomLevel={17} 
                        followUserMode={'normal'}
                        followUserLocation={true}
                        followZoomLevel={17}
                        animationDuration={1000}
                    />

                </MapboxGL.MapView>

                {renderLocationInfo()}

            </View>
)
}
```

Comment: In the `renderLocationInfo` you need to set the `onPress` to `onPress={() => setisStartL(true)}`

Comment: @AlistairNelson wow this so helpful a very small mistake, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

do the following:

```
    <MapboxGL.UserLocation
              renderMode="normal"
              visible={true}
              onUpdate={(location) => {
                  (!isStartL) ? console.log("not start yet") : onUserLocationUpdate(location)
              }}
   />
```

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

**Try that way**

```
  <MapboxGL.UserLocation
        renderMode="normal"
        visible={true}
        onUpdate={(location) => {
          isStartL
            ? onUserLocationUpdate(location)
            : console.log('not start yet');
        }}
      />
```

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

One approach is, move the if logic inside the `onUserLocationUpdate()` function.

If your state is false, just return from it. Otherwise, execute other steps.

This way, you can ensure the expected behavior.